# Finding resistance and voltage from Thevenin equivalent

Tags: potentiometer, thevenin

I am stuck on a homework problem where the objective is to compute the top and bottom resistance of a potentiometer and the voltage of the source.

I've gotten this far, but now I am stuck and am looking for pointers/tips in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Do know how to calculate Rth and Vos for a voltage divider?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This was just recently introduced in my class. I'm assuming that Rthevenin is just resulting value from the two resistors in the voltage divider

Comment: Rth = (Rtop * Rbottom)/(Rtop + Rbottom) and Voc = Rbottom/(Rtop + Rbottom)  So you have two equations and two unknowns, just solve.

Comment: For your Voc equation, do you not need to include the Vsource? Since I'm assuming it is a voltage divider

Comment: Yes, I forgot Vsource here you have it  Voc = Vsource*  Rbottom/(Rtop + Rbottom)

Comment: Sorry for the incessant questions, but how would I approach it with those two equations? I just need a point in the right direction, as I've tried solving for Vsource first, but that just gets me 10k/Rbottom and I get stuck. Thank you so much for your help so far

Comment: So you do not know how to solve simultaneous equations with two unknowns? So , you have Rh =100R , Rt +Rb = 10k and Voc =2V, right?